# How to list complete XML document using XSLT

Tags: xslt

What i'm looking for might seem pretty easy to understand, but i'm having a hard time making it possible.

I want to be able to put the content of an XML file on an HTML page using XSLT. The thing is, i want to list all the nodes name (not the content), recursively. Also, i have to consider the fact that i can't predict what are going to be the names of the nodes.

So if you know a way to recursively list all the nodes in an XML file using XSLT, thanks for the answer.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you want to output the source of an xml document onto an html page. Correct?

Comment: When you say "node" do you mean "element"? Do you also want to output anything from comments or processing instructions, etc?

Comment: There are many answers for question not much different than this one. It's also not clear whether you want all the names or the disctinct names. It would be better to post a reduce input sample and the exact desired output.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two different solutions (both short and easy) that produce two different versions of what you haven'r fully specified (all element names and all distinct element names).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you asked for the node names and not the content, you don't need to do it recursively, this is the simplest way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//node()">
           <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You know what, this seems so simple, it makes me want to hit my head on the wall for the next 30 minutes. To think that i just passed the whole day trying to figure something out with recursive template call and whatever other non-sense (like using a string variable containing a path in the select of a foreach). Thank you a lot. 

There's one thing though. If i use the value-of current(), it gives me the content of every child nodes. Is there a way of getting only the content of the node, and not is childs. Thanks again

Comment: `<xsl:template match="node()"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:apply-templates/> </xsl:template>` seems to do the same but even simpler :]

Comment: @mousio: you're correct thanks!
@Shadowxvii `<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>` should give you just the name of the current node.

Comment: If you want HTML yes or yes you can add the tag:
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes" />

Answer (score 3):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), '&#xA;')"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document (such as this):**

```
<Catalog name="AccessoriesCatalog">
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="1532" id="1532">
    </Category>
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="16115" id="16115">
        <ParentCategory>1532</ParentCategory>
    </Category>
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="16116" id="16116">
        <ParentCategory>16115</ParentCategory>
    </Category>
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="16126" id="16126">
        <ParentCategory>16115</ParentCategory>
    </Category>
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="16131" id="16131">
        <ParentCategory>1532</ParentCategory>
    </Category>
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="16132" id="16132">
        <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
    </Category>
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="16136" id="16136">
        <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
    </Category>
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="16139" id="16139">
        <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
    </Category>
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="16144" id="16144">
        <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
    </Category>
    <Category Definition="AccessoriesCategory"
    name="16195" id="16195">
        <ParentCategory>16131</ParentCategory>
    </Category>
</Catalog>
```

**produces the wanted output (a list of the names of all elements in the XML document):**

```
Catalog
Category
Category
ParentCategory
Category
ParentCategory
Category
ParentCategory
Category
ParentCategory
Category
ParentCategory
Category
ParentCategory
Category
ParentCategory
Category
ParentCategory
Category
ParentCategory
```

**In case only the distinct element names are wanted, then this transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kElemByName" match="*" use="name()"/>

 <xsl:template match="
  *[generate-id()
   =
    generate-id(key('kElemByName', name())[1])
   ]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), '&#xA;')"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
Catalog
Category
ParentCategory
```