# How to get a list of the distinct element names plus their attribute names using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to "scan" my xml files using xslt and get a list of the distinct element names **as well as** their attribute names.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dictionary>
    <entry>
        <form type="hyperlemma" xml:lang="cu">
            <note type="editor's comment">CHECK</note>
            <orth>hlE1</orth>
        </form>
        <form type="lemma" xml:lang="cu">
            <orth>lE1</orth>
        </form>
        <form type="variant" xml:lang="cu">
            <orth>var5</orth>
        </form>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <form type="hyperlemma" xml:lang="cu">
            <orth>hlE2</orth>
        </form>
        <form type="lemma" xml:lang="cu">
            <orth>lE2</orth>
        </form>
    </entry>
</dictionary>
```

A way to get a list of the distinct element names is documented in [How to list complete XML document using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861131/how-to-list-complete-xml-document-using-xslt) (please see Dimitre Novatchev's answer).

Using this stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="kElemByName" match="*" use="name(.)"/>

    <xsl:template match="
        *[generate-id()
        =
        generate-id(key('kElemByName', name(.))[1])
        ]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(.), '&#xA;')"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the (correct) output is

```
dictionary
entry
form
note
orth
```

Is it possible to get the attribute names, too? I would like to have the following output

```
dictionary
entry
form type="hyperlemma" xml:lang="cu"
form type="lemma" xml:lang="cu"
form type="variant" xml:lang="cu"
note type="editor's comment"
orth
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use XSLT 2.0 I would simply solve it using `for-each-group` and a grouping key computed from the name and attributes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="//*" group-by="string-join((name(), @*/concat(name(), '=&quot;', ., '&quot;')), ' ')">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(current-grouping-key(), '&#10;')"/>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That outputs

```
dictionary
entry
form type="hyperlemma" xml:lang="cu"
note type="editor's comment"
orth
form type="lemma" xml:lang="cu"
form type="variant" xml:lang="cu"
```

for me with Saxon 9.5.

If you want to sort the output you can use

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="//*" group-by="string-join((name(), @*/concat(name(), '=&quot;', ., '&quot;')), ' ')">
        <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(current-grouping-key(), '&#10;')"/>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
```

that way I get

```
dictionary
entry
form type="hyperlemma" xml:lang="cu"
form type="lemma" xml:lang="cu"
form type="variant" xml:lang="cu"
note type="editor's comment"
orth
```

I think to get a consistent result, the code would also first need to sort the attributes by name, as I suspect if the input has `<foo att1="value1" att2="value2"/>` and `<foo att2="value2" att1="value1"/>`, that you only want one element output.

That sorting could be performed with

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:function name="mf:sort" as="attribute()*">
      <xsl:param name="attributes" as="attribute()*"/>
      <xsl:perform-sort select="$attributes">
        <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
      </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="//*" group-by="string-join((name(), mf:sort(@*)/concat(name(), '=&quot;', ., '&quot;')), ' ')">
        <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(current-grouping-key(), '&#10;')"/>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using an XSLT 2.0 processor. Thank you very much for your help. My output now is `dictionary`, `entry`, `form type"hyperlemma" xml:lang"cu"`, `note type"editor's comment"`, `orth`. But why are `form type"lemma" xml:lang"cu"` and `form type"variant" xml:lang"cu"` (same `<form>` element, but different attribute name) not in the list?

Comment: I have rewritten my answer to use `for-each-group` as I think it is better doing that in case of XSLT 2.0 instead of using a key. My first suggestion only helped to output the attribute values of those elements the key identified but it did not try to distinguish elements based on name and attribute names and values as you seem to want to do. There might be some sorting left to be done to get the output as you posted.

Comment: Thank you so much for your (speedy) help! Thanks to your stylesheet, I now get the desired output.

Comment: Yes, if the input has `<foo att1="value1" att2="value2"/>` and `<foo att2="value2" att1="value1"/>`, I only want one element output.

Comment: I have added a sample doing a sort on the attributes by name.

Comment: Great! The sorting is a very useful feature I didn't even hope for. Now I have to look closer at the code in order to better understand how it works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler is to use `distinct-values()`:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(//*/string-join(
                         (name(), @*/concat(name(), '=&quot;', ., '&quot;')), ' '))" 
           separator="&#10;"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for another great solution! I wouldn't have thought it possible that you can get the desired output with even less lines of code...