# How to find list of all elements&attributes in a xml file from a Oracle table clob column?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, xmltype

I am trying to find all tags(including its XPATH) in an XML file which is placed in a CLOB Column in an oracle table. Could you please provide a query for this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list of unique tags can be generated with an XSL style sheet.

First create a simple table with an XML stored as a CLOB, using a random [sample XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762271(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
create table sample_xml(id number, some_xml clob);

insert into sample_xml values(1, q'[<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
   </book>
</catalog>]');
```

Now use [`XMLTRANSFORM`](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions254.htm#SQLRF06171) to convert the XML to a distinct set of tags, using the XML style sheet from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147061/how-to-get-a-list-of-the-distinct-element-names-plus-their-attribute-names-using):

```
select xmltransform(
    xmltype(some_xml), 
    xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:key name="kElemByName" match="*" use="name(.)"/>
    <xsl:template match="
        *[generate-id()
        =
        generate-id(key(''kElemByName'', name(.))[1])
        ]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(.), '''||chr(38)||'#xA;'')"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>')) tags
from sample_xml;


TAGS
----
catalog
book
author
title
```

You can get the results one-line-at-a-time by using `regexp_substr` to split the string:

```
select regexp_substr(replace(tags, chr(10), ','),'[^,]+', 1, level) from
(
    ... insert large query here
)
connect by regexp_substr(replace(tags, chr(10), ','),'[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

To see the attributes as well, check out the linked question, it also includes XML style sheets for getting attributes.

Comment: Thanks Jon for the response, above query did not return attribute column names in the result. 

How to get XPATH for all these elements in the result? 

Above result is showing in one record. is there any way that i can get this result in separate rows per each element. Thank you for your help again.

Comment: @SrinivasAvoonuri See my updated answer.