# Get list of XML element names

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm processing some XML that a supplier provides - unfortunately the XML for each row/record only includes the elements that have a value. For example:

```
<customerdata>
      <customerid>{123456}</customerid>
      <firstname>Peter</firstname>
      <surname>Jones</surname>
      <sex>M</sex>
      <dob>1991-04-09</dob>
      <address>1 Smith St</address>
      <city>Bondi</city>
      <postcode>2026</postcode>
      <phonehome>0212345678</phonehome>
      <phonework>0212345678</phonework>
      <phonemobile>0212345678</phonemobile>
      <email>test@test.com</email>
    </customerdata>
<customerdata>
      <customerid>{987654}</customerid>
      <firstname>Sally</firstname>
      <surname>Klemp</surname>
      <sex>F</sex>
      <dob>1987-09-05</dob>
      <address>4 Jones Parade</address>
      <city>Brisbane</city>
      <postcode>4000</postcode>
      <medicareno>0212345678</medicareno>
    </customerdata>
```

The first record has phonehome, phonework, phonemobile and email, whilst the 2nd record has  medicareno. I need to get a list of all the possible elements so I know what to look for when importing/processing the XML.

Is there a way I can programatically get a list of all possible elements that may be present in the XML?

Comment: *programmatically*? So what programming language are you using?

Comment: Sure. What language are you using (or do you want to use)? Have you searched for XML processing examples for your language of choice?  What did/didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer using XSLT - I wasn't sure if this was possible using Xpath or XSLT. Here's the link to the answer:

[How to list complete XML document using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861131/how-to-list-complete-xml-document-using-xslt)

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 2.0,

```
distinct-values(/*/customer-data/*/name())
```